# If I don't call clRelease* ,will it cause memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, opencl, chromium

I want to add some OpenCL support to Chromium, so I used APIs like `clCreateCommandQueue()`, but I can't find a proper place in Chromium to do cleanup.

So, if I don't call APIs like `clReleaseCommandQueue()`, will OS reclaim the memory after the process terminates? Or need I call it at the exit point of the process?

PS, The commandqueue is needed during the whole life of the process, so I just want to make sure it will not cause memory leak after process termination.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Is this not a job for atexit(3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the OpenCL objects are, ultimately, held by the device driver, you can't expect them to be automatically released once the application terminates.  That is always your job.

Comment: But if OpenCL objects are allocated in the memory block of the process, when the process exits, how can they still retain there? Because the device driver control them？

Comment: What makes you think that the entirety of each OpenCL object resides in the memory space allocated to your program?  I don't see any guarantee in the OpenCL standard.  In fact, pg 18 of the 1.2 spec talks about a reference count: "After the reference count reaches zero, the object’s resources are deallocated by OpenCL".  I take that as an indication that the OpenCL implementation holds part of the objects memory and will only release it when the appropriate clRelease* call is made.

Comment: Well, file handles also ultimately reside in the kernel; still they don't leak if a process terminates without closing them. OpenCL objects should not necessarily be different, but might of course be.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the OpenCL C++ wrapper (cl.hpp) then the compiler will figure out where to clean up your objects (when the referring object goes out of scope).

Comment: I guess that clean-up work relies on the destructors of classes. But Chromium may prevent destructors from running at fast closing, I think.